# "Carota" è un sostantivo femminile ma... le carote sono terribili o terribile?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, grammatical-number

"Carote" è un sostantivo femminile ma la frase "the carrots are terrible" è "le carote sono terribili" e non "le carote sono terribile".

Dov'è il mio errore?

Comment: Attento, la terza persona del verbo “essere” si scrive “è”, con l'accento, non “e”, che invece è una congiunzione.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Terribile* è un aggettivo della seconda classe, quindi al plurale maschile e femminile fa *terribili*. Lo stai confondendo con gli aggettivi della prima classe.

#### Prima classe

| Singolare | Plurale |
| --- | --- |
| bell**o** | bell**i** |
| bell**a** | bell**e** |

#### Seconda classe

| Singolare | Plurale |
| --- | --- |
| terribil**e** | terribil**i** |
| terribil**e** | terribil**i** |

C'è anche una terza classe molto meno comune:

| Singolare | Plurale |
| --- | --- |
| altruist**a** | altruist**i** |
| altruist**a** | altruist**e** |

Puoi trovare maggiori informazioni su come declinare gli aggettivi su https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/genere-e-numero-degli-aggettivi_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/ .

Comment: Tante grazie Federico!